# Python subprocess.Popen audio issues

Tags: python

I'm using a Raspberry Pi (running Jessie) and I have a USB audio adapter.  When I just type pianobar in the console, audio comes out of the USB audio adapter perfectly.  However when I do the following:

```
pianobar = subprocess.Popen("sudo -u pi pianobar", shell=True)
```

No audio comes out at all.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I have in my /etc/asound.conf file:

```
pcm.!default { 
  type hw
  card 1
}

ctl.!default {
  type hw
  card 1
}
```

and also in the /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf file I have modified:

```
defaults.ctl.card 0
defaults.pcm.card 0
```

to:

```
defaults.ctl.card 1
defaults.pcm.card 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I would check files opened in the app (e.g. with `ls -l /proc/<pianobar_pid>/fd/). I guess it's a permission problem but it's hard to know for sure.